# Select items from table where timestamps are within an hour of eachother

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgres (postgis) and i want to perform a query that returns all rows that have a timestamp within an hour of each other.

**What would the SQL statement look like?**

The table looks like this:

- id   { integer }
- name { character varying }
- timestamp { timestamp with time zone }

  ```
  id   name       timestamp
  ---+----------+--------------------------------
  1    one        "2010-09-24 21:10:39.515+00"
  2    two        "2010-09-16 09:21:09.362+00"
  3    three      "2010-07-08 00:00:46.549+00"
  ```

**EDIT #1**

Here's a better example. (with help from Tometzky) All the results are within 1 hour of each other. That is, for every row give me any other rows that are within 1 hour:

```
select * from myTable order by t

 id |               t               
----+-------------------------------
  9 | 2011-07-15 18:20:20.05+02
 10 | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02
 11 | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 13 | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02
 14 | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02
(5 rows)

result of needed query:

 id |  matchid |  origTime                  | matchTime
----+----------+----------------------------+------------------------------
  9 |   10     | 2011-07-15 18:20:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02
 10 |    9     | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02  | 2011-07-15 18:20:20.05+02
 10 |   11     | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 11 |   10     | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02
 11 |   13     | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02
 11 |   14     | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02
 13 |   11     | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 13 |   14     | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02
 14 |   11     | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 14 |   13     | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Within an hour of each other?  As in: 13:00, 13:59 and 14:35 would be in the same group?

Comment: Which version of Postgres? As from 8.4 Postgres have windowing functions which would help here.

Comment: @OMG : So for row id 2, anything between 8:21:09 and 10:21:09 would match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    t0.id, t1.id as matchid, 
    t0.ts as origTime, t1.ts as matchTime
from t t0
inner join t t1 on 
    t1.ts between 
        t0.ts - interval '1 hour'
        and 
        t0.ts + interval '1 hour'
    and t0.id != t1.id
;
```

Comment: But remember that you need an index on ts for reasonable performance.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting every possible combination with this query. That is one row matches all my rows and so forth. I'm getting matches that are years apart.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$ select * from test;
 id |               t               
----+-------------------------------
  9 | 2011-07-15 18:31:01.059487+02
 10 | 2011-07-15 18:31:01.55044+02
 11 | 2011-07-15 18:31:01.850583+02
 12 | 2011-07-15 18:31:02.064435+02
 13 | 2011-07-15 18:31:02.333449+02
 14 | 2011-07-15 18:31:02.727461+02
 15 | 2011-07-15 18:31:03.279447+02
 16 | 2011-07-15 18:31:03.642454+02
 17 | 2011-07-15 18:33:34.910252+02
 18 | 2011-07-15 18:33:35.995455+02
 19 | 2011-07-15 18:33:36.45246+02
(11 rows)

$ select id, lastid
  from (
    select id,
    t-lag(t) over (order by t) as lag,
    lag(id) over (order by t) as lastid from test
  ) as _
  where lag < '1 second';
 id | lastid 
----+--------
 10 |      9
 11 |     10
 12 |     11
 13 |     12
 14 |     13
 15 |     14
 16 |     15
 19 |     18
(8 rows)
```

Comment: There must be something wrong but not sure what it is. For example if 9 is 1 second from 10, then 10 is also 1 second from 9. Please take a look at my EDIT #1 i placed an example based on your example hoping it explains what i need better.

Comment: It wasn't clear what you wanted before an example. @Clodoado gave you correct answer.

Comment: Sorry (+1: for your effort and my mistake).